# Django server reload doesn't work for every .py file

Tags: python, django, django-q

I'm starting the django server with `python manage.py runserver`

The output is following

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

In my django app I have a file named services.py and one is called schedules.py. When I make changes in the services.py file the reload works as expected, in schedules.py file changes do not lead to a server reload.

Why is that?

As a further information in my schedules.py file I have a schedule, which is not working:

```
from django_q.tasks import schedule


schedule('api.shared.tasks.send_order_reminder',
         schedule_type='I',
         repeats=-1)
```

Having the same code in the services.py file creates a schedule

Comment: It does not load the file when you run the server, only when you (re)schedule.

Comment: what do you mean with reschedule?